# where in (sub query) vs join

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask about how to optimize my query. I am curious about the efficiency of using `join` instead of `where in` sub query. Can someone explain the difference?

```
SELECT  C.Customer_id,
        C.tran_id,
        t.date
    FROM CUSTOMERS C
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON c.Customer_id = t.Customer_id
    WHERE C.Customer_id IN (
        SELECT Customer_id FROM TRANSACTIONS_DATE WHERE tran_Date <= '2013-01-01'
    )
    AND C.Customer_id NOT IN(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Most query planners are smart enough to apply such a transformation for you (if possible). And a join is not necessary a replacement for an `IN` condition because the join might return multiple rows where the `IN` would only return a single row.

Comment: I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can move your subquery onto the join condition, as you're just looking for customers' transactions before or on 1st Jan 2013.

```
SELECT  C.Customer_id,
        C.tran_id,
        t.date
    FROM CUSTOMERs C
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON c.Customer_id= t.Customer_id
    AND t.tran_Date <= '2013-01-01'
  WHERE  C.Customer_id NOT IN(1,2,3)
```

Comment: sorry I write the wrong query from see my update

Comment: Your initial query is still wrong. You cannot select `c.customer_id` inside your sub query.

Comment: ok sorry it was typo it is  customer_id

Comment: Cool. So try the query I've posted above

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well it wasn't when I posted my answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You may get better performance using EXISTS instead of IN, like so:

```
SELECT  C.Customer_id,
        C.tran_id,
        t.date
    FROM CUSTOMERS C
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T ON c.Customer_id= t.Customer_id
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM TRANSACTIONS_DATE td 
            WHERE 
                td.tran_Date <= '2013-01-01' 
                AND td.Customer_id = c.Customer_id
           ) AND
        C.Customer_id NOT IN(1,2,3)
```

The query plan may be optimizing this for you already, but it can't hurt to experiment. I'd also perhaps try a NOT EXISTS to replace the `Customer_ID NOT IN` piece to see if there is a difference.